# Application runs in Eclipse, exported jar crashes

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, executable-jar, jvm-arguments

Inside my Swing application I have to parse xml documents. Sometimes they have more than 190 MB. It caused crashes in applications because no enough memory could be allocated. Inside Eclipse I changed JVM arguments so it can allocate up to 2gb of memory using this argument:

```
-Xmx2048m
```

When I start it like this there are no problems.
But when I exported it to runnable jar file app keeps crashing. I changed the JVM memory settings for my Windows environment

```
ControlPanel->Programms->Java->Java-View
```

It crashes at the following line:

```
 doc = docBuilder.parse(inputSource);
```

But no exception is thrown. For this reason I think my JVM crashes. What could be the problem?

Comment: When you launch your .jar do you also do something like `java -jar yourFile.jar -Xmx2048m` ?

Comment: No. I have a runnable jar. It's a swing application. The problem occurs just when I get such a big xml file

Comment: OutOfMemoryException requires you to catch Throwable instead of Exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a BAT and double-click that instead of your JAR.

MyApp.bat:

```
@ echo off
java -Xmx2048m -jar MyJar.jar
```

Or better yet, wrap the JAR in an EXE that also sets the JVM parameters.  A tool like [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) can do this.